# Flash 64-Bit UEFI on Intel Baytrail Tablet

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, 64-bit, uefi

Is it possible to flash a 64-bit UEFI on an Intel BayTrail Tablet which currently has a 32-Bit UEFI? I tried to install a 64-Bit Ubuntu 14.04 (which surprisingly worked) but after the installation my system can't boot from it and just loads the EFI-Shell on startup. It would be really great if i could run 64-bit software on that tablet.
Any ideas or guys who tried it?

I also found a document on the internet http://www.shopmanda.com/public/Companion%20AVA/Inari-BringUpGuide-004-x64-RevA.pdf which displays the steps to update to a 64-bit uefi but i can't find the file which is mentioned in the pdf.

EDIT:

okay, i found the files: http://www.shopmanda.com/public/Companion%20AVA/Inari%208/Inari%208/  The inari has nearly the same hardware as my tablet (also a intel baytrail processor and 2GB RAM). I think i will try it...

Comment: Where are you going to get the firmware for that device from?

Comment: That's a good question. I just wanted to know if someone has a 64-bit firmware (or knows where i can find one) for one of those cheap tablets which are all based on the intel atom baytrail processors and have 1 or 2 gig of ram (i think they have all more or less the same pieces of hardware inside them).

Comment: I highly doubt it's available, but maybe someone else knows.

Comment: I found a document on the internet: http://www.shopmanda.com/public/Companion%20AVA/Inari-BringUpGuide-004-x64-RevA.pdf but i can't find the file :(

Comment: You should edit your question and include all the information you've found so far. Also, personally even if I found that file I'd be loathe to try it on my tablet unless I didn't care about bricking it.

Comment: okay, i found the files: http://www.shopmanda.com/public/Companion%20AVA/Inari%208/Inari%208/  The inari has nearly the same hardware as my tablet (also a intel baytrail processor and 2GB RAM). I think i will try it...

Comment: Cool, best of luck and be sure to share your experience as a complete answer below. BTW, what's the exact make and model of your tablet?

Comment: It is a german tablet called "One Xcellent 10".

Comment: Use the 32Bit EFI with a 64Bit Ubuntu. http://askubuntu.com/a/392775. I tested this on my Toshiba Encore 8 and it works. But Ubuntu doesn't work fine with touch

Comment: Will 64Bit Windows work?

Comment: I've tried the 32Bit EFI file from a 32Bit Windows 8.1 but it doesn't work.

Comment: @binaryBigInt [Installing Windows x64 on 32-bit UEFI (EFI-IA32) via GRUB](https://superuser.com/q/1055305/241386)